# ListAdapter getView called after onPause when the device is locked and is in landscape orientation

Tags: android, listview

I have an application that uses a listview.

Update and more clear explanation of the situation as requested below: 
After the question asked bellow I think I figured out the exact sequence where the issue occurs:

1. start the application
2. go to landscape orientation
3. lock the screen -> this forces portrait orientation since the lock screen is in portrait orientation
4. onPause() of the Fragment and Activity that are on screen is called
5. after ~1 second Adapter.getView() is called for the items of the ListView that used the be on screen
6. unlock the screen
7. onResume is called

My best guess is that at step 5 getView() is called because the lock screen is in portrait orientation. Looks like Android tries to re-layout the application screen to portrait although this is not needed because the screen is locked.

Is this expected and normal? I built my logic around the fact that onResume of the activity/fragment that was on screen will be always called before any other coding.

Comment: The sequence is not to see in the stacktrace. So why should we look at it? You did not tell if onResume() follows getView() then.

Comment: I've rewritten the question with the exact sequence and a possible explanation of the reason. Hope that helps

Comment: This is very different from what i understood first. You better change `3. lock the screen` to `3. lock the screen. The lockscreen forces portrait orientation`. As that is crucial info the user needs right away.

Answer (score 1):

So I managed to confirm that the reason for that behavior is following:

- The application is in landscape orientation when the screen gets locked
- The lock screen itself is fixed in portrait orientation

Android forces re-layout of the application that is "bellow" the lock screen just because both are fixed in different orientation.

I found no way to prevent this except from enforcing application screen orientation which is not an option in my case. The only workaround that I found is to put following coding at the start of each Adapter.getView() implementation.

```
  public View getView(int index, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (Utils.isScreenLocked()) {
            return aConvertView;
        }
  }
```

The isScreenLocked() method uses the KeyGuardManager to check whether the screen is locked or not.